# Errors when trying to install PyDev in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev

After installing the PyDev plugin for Eclipse (by feeding http://pydev.org/updates in Eclipse's *Install new Software* window) I'm getting the following errors when launching Eclipse:

[image: errors]

What is it? What should I do?

I'm using Eclipse 4.2.0.

Comment: Try installing PyDev through the Eclipse Marketplace instead.

Comment: @Amir: Thanks, though I've tried installing through the Marketplace and I still get the same error.

Comment: @Amir: Your solution has worked after making a fresh new copy of Eclipse. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better using Eclipse Marketplace, [from the website](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/) or through Eclipse itself, instead of providing the direct link.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you have a link to the Aptana Studio update site in your updates and you're marking to check all update sites.

As PyDev has optional dependencies on Aptana Studio, it'll gather those plugins, but getting Aptana Studio that way (partially) doesn't work properly. So, uncheck the option to get updates considering all update sites during the install process or remove the aptana studio update site.